# How does kafka-consumer work during reparations?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can the following situation happen, when I create the consumer and immediately invoke `consumer.pool(1000)`, the consumer doesn't consume messages which the topic contains.

Is it possible the same situation happens when I have the topic (with 4 partitions) and add new consumer in the same consumer groups, and the old consumer on operation `oldConsumer.pool(100)` returns 0 records.

I didn't find the description of this process in the documentation but I can reproduce this situation on my local machine many times

Comment: Re-partitioning does not take place when a new consumer is added to the consumer group. Do you mean partition assignment?